# Temporary variable to hold RDD in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I;m not really sure how to describe this in the shortest possible sentence, but i'll try anyway. Say that I have a RDD in this format in a variable called **data**

```
(a,b,c)
```

b and c are arrays resulting from previous RDD transformation. Based on certain conditions, I want to transform the RDD to get only 1 column from either b or c. I'm having problem declaring temporary variable to store the rdd.

```
val data = sc.textFile("1.txt").map(_.split(",",-1))
//var new_data:RDD= null??? what data type should i use??
if(x ==1){
    new_data = data.map{ (a,b,c) => ( b(x) ) }
}else if( x==2 ){
    new_data = data.map{ (a,b,c) => ( c(x) ) }
}
//several more if statement here similar to the two above

//need to use new_data here
```

If i use **val** to declare new_data within the **if** statement, it will be out of scope out of the if statement. I tried using var, but i dont know how to initialize it. I tried using **var** of type MappedRDD and RDD, but i can;t seem to assign the value of the map operation to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wrap the if in a function. DUUUUUH!! sorry. new to functional programming. should have thought more before posting. so the code goes like:

```
val new_data = { 
   if(x ==1){ data.map{ (a,b,c) => ( b(x) ) }         
   else if( x==2 ){ data.map{ (a,b,c) => ( c(x) ) 
}
```